# How to dynamically create column names for dataframe based on shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a dataframe from a list of lists where some "rows" have 3 "columns" and some have 20, for example. I don't know because this is parsing a text file to generate the list. The data is all strings.

I have tried the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=myArray)
df_xrefs.columns(['Column A', 'Column B'] + ['DynamicColumn_{}'+format(x) for x in range(1, int(df.shape[1])-1)])
```

I expect the columns to be:

```
 'Column A', 'Column B', 'DynamicColumn_1, DynamicColumn_2' ... 'DynamicColumn_n'
```

```
TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable
```

With my current test data, the output of the following is 5

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=myArray)
print(df.shape[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing the reassignment of columns with equals.

```
df_xrefs.columns = (['Column A', 'Column B'] + ['DynamicColumn_{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, int(df_xrefs.shape[1])-1)])
```